# Convert base64 to Image in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC#. When i try To convert to base64 string to image, the image is not getting opened. I am getting base64 string from javascript and coverting that to image in controller. Here's my code.

```
var base64 = "data:image/png;base64,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...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";

byte[] str = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(base64);
var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(str));
var file = Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/err.png");
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file, buffer);
Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/err.png");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I copied that base64 string prompt window. I used ajax method for posting the base64 string from client and it works for me

C#

```
[HttpPost]
public void Base64ToImage(string source)
{
    string base64 = source.Substring(source.IndexOf(',') + 1);
    base64 = base64.Trim('\0');
    byte[] chartData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
}
```

AJAX Method

```
var picture = jqplotToImg($('#ChartContent'));
//prompt("", picture);

$.ajax({ type: 'POST',
    url: '../Report/Base64ToImage',
    async: false,
    data: { source: picture },
    success: function (data) {
        //alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Once you have the image (chartData) how do you actually save it somewhere onthe server in your controller, i tried chartdata.SaveAs but that doesnt work...

Comment: @dave317 Do you mean, to save the file created from the base64 String?

Answer (score 25):

Your code is totally wrong.

You need to parse out the actual base64 data from that string, by removing everything before the first comma.

You can then call `Convert.FromBase64String()` on that data.

```
string source = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABG4...YII=";
string base64 = source.Substring(source.IndexOf(',') + 1);
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```

Comment: Thanks again, This error is produced `The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.`

Comment: You did use the full Base 64 string, and not the abbreviated one from this anwser?

Comment: @Codo, Thanks, I am not taking the example string here. I am using it from my source

Comment: A useful link answering the same -> http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/e6d71127-1f12-4555-879b-6a859947eafa.aspx