# Bind data:image/png;base64 image format to Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, drop-down-menu

I am doing a Web, Visual Studio 2013, C# Application. I need to bind an Image to a asp:DropDownList.
So far, all post I read do the same stuff.

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlnick" CssClass="ddlnick" Width="400px" runat="server" DataTextField="Picture"  DataValueField="User_id"  onselectedindexchanged="ddlNick_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and when I load the data from Database

```
foreach (ListItem li in ddlnick.Items)
        {
            if (li.Text != "")
                li.Attributes["title"] = li.Value;
        }
```

where li.value is the phisical path to the picture...

My problem it that I have the picture in the database with format

```
data:image/png;base64
```

and i could not find the way to bind it to the dropdownlist.

It is posible?

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you to bind your image path: [Convert base64 to Image in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178737/convert-base64-to-image-in-c-sharp)

I hope this helps, sorry to answer and not comment, I 'm not able to comment due to reputation...

Answer (score 0):

If all the images in your database are separated with "/" character you can split the character and have a two dimensional lists: one of them can contain images and the other can contain the format. then you can create a list of bitmaps from all different images and then bind your dropdown to the bitmap lists.
However if there are so many images you have to careful about the memory management.