# Web API Pass File Data as Parameter

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-web-api

The "normal" way of accepting file uploads in Web API is to examine the the `Request.Content`. However, I'd like to have the file data be an actual parameter of the method, so that tools like [NSwag](https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag) are able to generate proper TypeScript clients.

So instead of stuff like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task UploadFile()
    {            
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(Path.GetTempPath());
        var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        var formData = result.FormData.GetValues("Path");
        ...
    }
```

I just want something like this:

```
 public async Task UploadFileInfo(Models.FileInfo fileInfo)
 {
     //FileInfo contains a string of the binary data, decode it here
 }
```

I have this partly working except that I can't reliably encode the binary file data as a string in JavaScript and then decode it for saving in C#/.NET.

In JavaScript, I've tried `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer`, `FileReader.readAsBinaryString`, `FileReader.readAsDataURL`, `FileReader.readAsText`, but none of these have produced a string of binary data that I can reliably decode. In C#, I've tried `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` and/or `Convert.FromBase64String`.

For reference, the relevant code NSwag is generating to communicate with the Web API is as follows:

```
    const content_ = JSON.stringify(fileInfo);

    let options_ : any = {
        body: content_,
        observe: "response",
        responseType: "blob",
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Content-Type": "application/json", 
        })
    };

    return this.http.request("post", url_, options_)
```

where `this.http` is an Angular `HttpClient`.

Comment: You can convert the file blob to a base-64 encoded string in both JavaScript and C#.

Comment: In our applications we did so, but notice the base64 related size "overhead"

Comment: @Jasen Can you post code showing the client and web API code? I've tried a bunch of combinations of the FileReader methods but can't get it to work.

Comment: @DotNetDev ditto.

Comment: when I'm at work tomorrow I check our source

Comment: Here's a [JavaScript conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript). Then you treat it like a string for the transport request. Your controller will need to [convert the string param back into a blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178737/convert-base64-to-image-in-c-sharp).

Comment: @Jasen JS's `FileReader.readAsDataUrl()` and .NET's  `Convert.FromBase64String()` aren't properly encoding/decoding in a format that each other understands. I get `The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character...` errors.

Comment: Scratch my previous comment. It works if you do `source.Substring(source.IndexOf(',') + 1)` first. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

FileDto

```
[DataContract]
public class RestFileDataDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "data", IsRequired = true)]
    [Required]
    public string Data { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "filename")]
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
```

Base64-Persistence

```
public void SaveFile(string data, string filePath)
{
    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
    if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
    }

    using (FileStream outputStream = File.Create(filePath))
    {
        using (Stream inputStream = new MemoryStream(new Base64Converter().ConvertToByteArray(data)))
        {
            inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Current);
            inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("route")]
public HttpResponseMessage Upload([FromBody] RestFileDataDto fileImage)
{
    //// call persistence
}
```

Base64Converter().ConvertToByteArray

```
public byte[] ConvertToByteArray(string base64String)
{
    var splittedString = base64String.Split(',');
    return Convert.FromBase64String(splittedString[splittedString.Length - 1]);
}
```

Comment: Is your `new Base64Converter()` supposed to be `Convert.FromBase64String()`? .NET doesn't have a class called `Base64Converter` as far as I can tell.

Comment: When I use `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` on the JavaScript side and `Convert.FromBase64String()` on the .NET side I get the `The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character...` error. So that method doesn't work.

Comment: sry, yes its a not a .NET Class, I'll update the code